# Django won't let me save a User object

Tags: python, django, django-models, python-2.7

When I call `User.create_user`, I get the following error:

```
IntegrityError at /login
users_user.status_id may not be NULL
```

Note: I have looked at a bunch of other IntegrityError questions on SO, and I couldn't fix this problem.

My models look like this:

```
class Status(models.Model):
    status = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    status_time = models.DateTimeField('date published')

    def __init__(self, status = '', time=timezone.datetime.min, *args, **kwargs):
        self.status = status
        self.status_time = time
        super(Status, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def set_status(self, s):
        self.status = s
        self.status_time = timezone.datetime.now()
        self.save()

    def get_status(self):
        now = timezone.datetime.now()
        if now-self.status_time<datetime.timedelta(minutes=15):
            return self.status
        return None

class User(models.Model):
    facebook_id = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    friends = ListField()
    status = models.OneToOneField(Status)

    @classmethod
    def create_user(cls, fid, friends):
        k = User()
        k.facebook_id = fid
        k.friends = friends
        k.save() #THE PROBLEM IS HERE
        k.status = Status()
        k.status.set_status('')
        k.status.save()
        k.save()
```

I also still don't understand what User.status_id represents.  Why is it there, and why can it not be `None`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you save your user with an uncreated status. Create a status first, then you can save the user:

```
   def create_user(cls, fid, friends):
        k = User()

        k.status = Status()
        k.status.set_status('') # set_status saves the status

        k.facebook_id = fid
        k.friends = friends
        k.save()
```

Or better yet:

```
   def create_user(cls, fid, friends):
        status = Status()
        status.set_status('')
        User.objects.create(facebook_id=fid, friends=friends, status=status)
```

In idiomatic django code, methods like `create_user` should be on the models' manager:

```
class UserManager(models.Manager):
    def create_user(self, fid, friends):
        status = Status()
        status.set_status('')
        return self.create(facebook_id=fid, friends=friends, status=status)


class User(models.Model):
    facebook_id = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    friends = ListField()
    status = models.OneToOneField(Status)

    objects = UserManager()
```

Then you call it like this:

```
new_user = User.objects.create_user(fid, friends)
```

Then you notice you could've just used the builtin `objects.create`, if only there were a default status:

```
# A custom manager is no longer needed

class User(models.Model):
    facebook_id = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    friends = ListField()
    status = models.OneToOneField(Status)

    def save(self, *a, **kw):
        # if this user doesn't have a status yet, create an empty one
        if self.status is None:
            self.status = Status()
            self.status.set_status('')

        super(User, self).save(*a, **kw)

# creating users:

new_user = User.objects.create(facebook_id=fid, friends=friends)

# status is set to an empty one automatically in save
```

Comment: Perfect! This worked like a charm.  I actually have another question on this same project, and since you seem to be knowledgeable about this, I was wondering if you could help me there too? It's at
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15712582/my-status-object-is-not-saving-in-django
Thanks!