# My Status object is not saving in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, python-2.7

When I enter the shell, I run into the following problem:

```
from users.models import Status
from django.utils import timezone

Status.objects.all()
>>> []
p = Status()
p.status_time = timezone.datetime.min
p.status_time
>>> datetime.datetime(1, 1, 1, 0, 0)
p.save()
Status.objects.all()
>>> [<Status: Status object>]
print(Status.objects.all()[0].status_time)
>>> None
```

I don't understand why the `status_time` is not saving properly.  My Status model is below:

```
class Status(models.Model):

    status = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    status_time = models.DateTimeField('date published')

    def __init__(self, status = '', time=timezone.datetime.min, *args, **kwargs):
        self.status = status
        self.status_time = time
        super(Status, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Could someone please explain this behavior and possibly suggest a fix?

Comment: What database do you use? Does it support datetimes that far in the past?

Comment: I'm using sqlite3 which as far as I can see is cool with datetime.datetime.min

Comment: Pavel, I can confirm that I get the same problem if i replace `timezone.datetime.min` with `timezone.datetime.now()` so that's not the problem.

Vken, I don't think so.  I want to set `status_time` to `time`.

Comment: Oops, my bad, misread the arguments passed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I told you before, you need to read the documentation and follow the tutorial. This is not the way to set a default value for a model's field. Please go through the documentation and tutorial at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ If you run into problems during it, come back and ask questions, but if you continue to things incorrectly you are just forming bad habits.

---

I realize that the original content may seem aggressive, that was not the intent. I just want to prevent you from doing things your way as opposed to the way they are designed to be done and wasting tons of your time in the process (I've done it before). That being said, I will try and demonstrate how the designers of django would most likely have wanted you to set up your model.

```
class Status(models.Model):
    status = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    time = models.DateTimeField('date published', default=timezone.datetime.min)
```

As you can see, there is no `__init__` used when creating models. You simply give it fields as properties. Each field type has several options to set things like default values, max_length, etc...

Comment: Thanks - you're dead right.  I changed it to

    `class Status(models.Model):
        status = models.CharField(max_length=200, default = '')
        status_time = models.DateTimeField('date published', default=timezone.datetime.min)`

and it worked.

Comment: Also, @Abs I updated the answer as it seemed a bit harsh when I wasn't trying to be.

Comment: No probs! Sometimes being harsh is what it takes to change bad habits haha.

Answer (score 0):

why not simply do:

class Status(models.Model):

```
status = models.CharField(max_length=200)
status_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Which will add a date time object automatically once a `Status` instance is created. More info [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#datetimefield)

Comment: It looks like he wants to set it to `timezone.datetime.min` which is not the same as `auto_now_add`